# Retaining one member of a pair

Tags: linux, bash, awk, duplicates

Good afternoon to all,

I have a file containing two fields, each representing a member of a pair. 
I want to retain one member of each pair and it does not matter which member as these are codes for duplicate samples in a study.

Each pair appears twice in my file, with each member of the pair appearing once in either column.

An example of an input file is:

`XXX1 XXX7
XXX2 XXX4
abc2 dcb3
XXX7 XXX1
dcb3 abc2
XXX4 XXX2`

And an example of the desired output would be

```
XXX1
XXX2
abc2
```

How might this be accomplished in bash? Thank you.

Comment: Or, should `XXX4` be in the output? Also, does each pair appear in the file in both orientations (like in the example input?)

Comment: why is `xxx2` and `xxx4` in the output? They belong both to the set `{xxx2, xxx4}`

Comment: Can we change the output sequence by sorting it?

Comment: Sorry Lars, XXX4 should not have been in the output. That was a mistake on my part. The output sequence can be sorted. 

dcb3 is not in the output as that is a member of a pair which includes abc2, which is in the output. Only one member of a pair should be in the output. It doesn't matter which, dcb3 or abc2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a combination of GNU awk, cut and sort, store the scipt as `duplicatePairs.awk`:

```
    { if ( $1 < $2) print $1, $2
      else print $2, $1
    }
```

and run it like this: `awk -f duplicatePairs.awk your_file | sort -u | cut -d" " -f1`

The if sorts the pairs such that a line with `x,y` and a line with `y,x` will be printed the same. Then `sort -u` can remove the duplicate lines. And the `cut` selects the first column.

---

With a slightly larger awk script, we can solve the requirements "awk-only":

```
    { 
     smallest = $1;
     if ( $1 > $2) {
        smallest = $2
     }

     if( !(smallest in seen) ) {
        seen [ smallest ] = 1
        print smallest
     }
    }
```

Run it like this: `awk -f duplicatePairs.awk your_file`

Comment: @Joni Thanks for the hint, I updated the answer with a pipe to cut, which works like your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer posted by Lars above works very well I would like to suggest an alternative, just in case someone stumbles upon this problem.

I had previously used `awk '!seen[$2,$1]++ {print $1}'` to the same result. I didn't realize it had worked since the number of lines in my file wasn't halved. This turned out to be because of some wrong assumptions I made about my data.